# How to get substring of a string in ANT property

Tags: ant

I have a requirement to get a substring out of a string in to [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) property.

Example string:

```
1=tibunit-1.4.2.projlib\=
```

I want to extract the part before `.projlib\=` and after the first `=`.

The result should be:

```
tibunit-1.4.2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Your results contains `.projectlib\=` yet your questions states you want the part before that.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in question.. my output should 'tibunit-1.4.2'

Answer (score 3):

Use [script task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) with builtin javascript engine (JDK >= 1.6.0_06) and something like :

if you need substring 'tibunit-1.4.2.projlib\' :

```
<project>

 <property name="foo" value="1=tibunit-1.4.2.projlib\="/>

 <script language="javascript">
  // simple echo
  println(project.getProperty('foo').split('=')[1]);
  // create property for later use
  project.setProperty('foobar', project.getProperty('foo').split('=')[1]);
 </script>

 <echo>$${foobar} => ${foobar}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[script] tibunit-1.4.2.projlib\
[echo] ${foobar} => tibunit-1.4.2.projlib\
```

if you need substring 'tibunit-1.4.2' :

```
<project>

 <property name="foo" value="1=tibunit-1.4.2.projlib\="/>

 <script language="javascript">
  s = project.getProperty('foo').split('=')[1];
  // simple echo
  println(s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(".")));
  // create property for later use
  project.setProperty('foobar', s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(".")));
 </script>

 <echo>$${foobar} => ${foobar}</echo>

</project>
```

output:

```
[script] tibunit-1.4.2
[echo] ${foobar} => tibunit-1.4.2
```

For reuse put that stuff into a [macrodef](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).

Comment: `javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "println" is not defined in <eval> at line number 4
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:451)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:403)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)`

Comment: The following code worked for `println`:
`<script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
   echo = project.createTask("echo");
   echo.setMessage(project.getProperty('foo').split('=')[1]);
   echo.perform();
]]> </script>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the ant-contrib task [PropertyRegex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) :

```
<propertyregex property="tibunit.version"
               input="1=tibunit-1.4.2.projlib\="
               regexp="1=(tibnunit-[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+).+"
               select="\1"
               casesensitive="false" />
```